# Rutas relativas

Tags: php, mysql

Sé que hay mucha información, pero no consigo incluir el archivo de conexión. Quiero que `registrar.php` incluya a `conexion.php` las ubicaciones de los archivos son las siguientes:

**registrar.php:**

```
c:\xampp4\htdocs\php\usuarios\registrar.php
```

**conexion.php:**

```
c:\xampp4\htdocs\php\conexion.php
```

En registrar.php he intentado poner

```
require('../conexion.php');
```

Pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Al colocar `require('../conexion.php');` únicamente subes un nivel en la jerarquía, para lograr llegar donde quieres necesitas poner `require('../../conexion.php');`, este esquema quizá te ayude a visualizarlo mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]