# Wordpress - redireccionar URL de logotipo de sitio web

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy haciendo un gestor de proyectos en WordPress, y lo que trato de hacer es básicamente lo siguiente, que un usuario, cuando este dentro de su sesión y haga click en el logotipo del proyecto, lo redireccione al mismo sitio, es decir, a la pagina donde esta alojado el sistema en su sesión, y no a la página de inicio.
Traté de utilizar la función de php asi:

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('shortcode_logo'))
{
    function shortcode_logo(){

        $url = "https://planner.plazalasglorias.com/";

        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            $url = "#";
        }

        ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
                    <img src="https://planner.plazalasglorias.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Logo-Planner-System-04.png" alt=">
                </a>
        <?php
    }
    add_shortcode('code_short', 'hortcode_logo');
}

?>
```

Cualquier ayuda o consejo seria util.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no sé muy bien el error que tienes, pero a simple vista me di cuenta de algunos errores. Cómo que estás encerrando código html dentro de una función que no estás llamando. Creo que sería bueno si lo estructuras de esta manera donde primero se hacen las validaciones y dependiendo de eso se asigna la variable con la URL correspondiente.

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('shortcode_logo')) {
    function shortcode_logo(){

        $url = "https://planner.plazalasglorias.com/";

        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $url = "#";
        }
    }
    shortcode_logo();
    add_shortcode('code_short', 'hortcode_logo');
}

?>
<a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
    <img src="*Tu imagen*" alt="">
</a>´
```

Answer (score 0):

debes utilizar rutas relativas de esa manera evitarás tener que definir cada ruta en el htaccess.

Mira este ejemplo:
[Rutas relativas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381009/rutas-relativas)